# SQL Server dts package

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, dts

I am currently using Visual Studio 2010 and have few DTS packages to debug. I am not able to view those DTS Packages which I have tried installing the dts run time. backward compatibility for my sql server 2008. but could not figure out a way to see these packages and edit them. 
Does anyone have any Suggestions on how to View DTS Packages

Comment: Are these legacy SQL Server 2000 DTS packages or SSIS packages?

Comment: You have Visual Studio 2010 but do you have SQL Server 2008 or SQL Server 2012 installed. DTS support only goes up through [2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500440(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: @ConcernedOfTunbridgeWells These are Legacy DTS Packages..not SSIS Packages

Comment: @billinkc I have 2008 installed too with backward compatibility,but I am having problem in Migrating DTS Packages to SSIS

Comment: SSIS has runtime support for DTS packages up to 2008R2 (IIRC) but not opening and editing them; DTS support is dropped entirely in 2012.  If you want to modify DTS packages you will need to get hold of a copy of SQL Server 2000.  There is no DTS-SSIS migration path.  You will have to re-build your packages by hand.